# -bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_us.utf-8)

Tags: bash, macos, utf-8

After I upgrade my Mac from Sierra to High Sierra, I got the setlocale warning when I use Terminal SSH to connect to Centos (6 and 7).

Thought there are a few workaround to the problems, I found the problem was that the locale environment variables in `.bash_profile` are in all lower case `en_us.utf-8`. Changing it to `en_US.UTF-8`  fixed the problems.

Other solutions I tried, found on the Internet were:

In CentOS (the server)

- Set `LC_LANG=en_US.utf8` in `/etc/environments` fix the problem.

In Mac (the client)

- Remove SendEnv LC in ssh_config fix the problem

If I run `locale -a`, the locale is

`en_US.utf8` on CentOS and

`en_US_UTF-8` on MacOS

It seems the normalization procedures of locale variables in CentOS and MacOS are different. On CentOS, it seems it normalizes `UTF-8` to lowercase and will remove the hyphen but requires `en_US` in this exact case.  On MacOS, it seems it normalizes to uppercase and needs the hyphen and accepts any case mix for `en_US`.  So a compatible setting is `en_US.UTF-8` where the three letters `UTF` can be in any case.

(That is why I cannot fix the problem by I setting the locale variables to `en_US.utf8` in Mac, it will change the `LC_ALL` to blank.)

So what is the standard normalization procedure?  Or is there a standard?

Another thing I don't understand is why it only happened after I upgraded to High Sierra. I found my `.bash_profile` setting was using `en_us.utf-8` so why did I not get the warning message earlier? The two possible guesses are

- High Sirrea changed the ssh_config after upgrade (by adding SendEnv), or
- Sierra normalizes the LC_ALL environments variable in Terminal.

Comment: Are you sure that the cause was not server side? The white-list of env variables from SSH client (or changes on Centos locale aliases, I'm noticing that also Debian removed the - in the UTF-8. I think maybe because hyphen is used to split fields.

Comment: The first warning I encounter was suspected in the server side, which I fixed it by setting the /etc/environments.  But then the same problem found in other servers, I have many servers.  Then I think I cannot update every servers environment.  Which lead me to look into a solution in the client side.  Since I have just upgrade my Mac Air (accidentally), I then think that it may be due to the upgrade.  Also, I did not get report from my colleagues.  Eventually, I found the problems was my setting in the bash_profile and in ssh_config.

Comment: You can set a env variable on your local `.ssh/config` https://superuser.com/questions/48783/how-can-i-pass-an-environment-variable-through-an-ssh-command (the second answer)

Answer (score 0):

For language part, there is a sort of standardization: BCP47 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646). This say that language identifier is case independent, but better to follow the standard case as described in the RFC (lower case for language, upper case for country, just the initial upper case for script). Java refers to such standard for locale setting: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html#util-text (but just language identifier, no encoding). JavaScript is similar (but it expand locales with the `-u-xxxx` suffixes). (C and Python just interface with system locale).

POSIX (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html) say that `The contents of this string are implementation-defined`.  LSB refer just to POSIX and a discussion (without link) on ISO about non conflicting names: https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/localization.html

Wikipedia list an other ISO standard for POSIX, but it is not cited in current POSIX, and that standard registry has only few Nordic countries.

So, as far I know, there is no standardization. The language tag identifier is standardized (the part before the `.` (dot), but nothing say that language part of a locale identifier should follow that.

Answer (score -6):

locate -a

lan1
lan2
…

export LC_ALL="lan 1"

Comment: This answer is bizarre and totally wrong.

Comment: I think that the poster meant to write "locaLe -a" instead of "locaTe -a" (lowercase letter "L" instead of "t"). Also, the list of languages is separated by spaces, but should be separated by linefeeds. If you list the locales using "locale -a" and then use that value to set LC_ALL, you will get the write spelling of the locale on your system. If "locale -a" doesn't list the locale you want, you have to generate it. On my system, the following file lists all possible locales: /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED. Get the correct spelling of the locale name from that file, then use the program locale-gen.